# CSS > Highlight first row if more than 2 columns wide

Tags: css

I want to apply styling to a table made up solely of `<td>`'s, to highlight a header row/column, based on the number of columns in a table.

The trick is, I don't want it to clash with tables that do have a `<th>` cells setup correctly.

**Browser:** Chrome v53 (64bit on MacOS)

**What I've tried:** http://jsbin.com/tacevu/edit?html,css,output

I'm almost there, I just can't highlight the first row if a table has more than 2 columns  (i.e. scenario "Table 4"). Perhaps Chrome doesn't support the `!` parent selector?

```
/* highlight first ROW if > 2 columns*/
tr:first-child! td:nth-last-child(4) { background-color:blue; }
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table 4</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This n+3 child for more than 2 child

```
 tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(n+3) ~ td,
 tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(n+3):first-child{
    background-color: blue;
```

### }

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
/* highlight TH */

th {
  background-color: red;
}
/* highlight first COLUMN if 2 columns */

td:nth-last-child(2):first-child {
  background-color: lime;
}
/* highlight first ROW if > 2 columns*/

tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(n+3) ~ td,
tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(n+3):first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table 1</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
  <caption>Table 2</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
  <caption>Table 3</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <th>bbb</th>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <th>bbb</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
  <caption>Table 4</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PC: [http://lea.verou.me](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a parent selector in CSS. That rule is probably being ignored because of the `!`. That's why it's not working.

Comment: `!` is called subject selector but not widely supported. some people call it 'parent selector' because it changes natural left-to-right selection order in css.

Comment: Ahh, I see that was a syntax in the CSS4 spec that has since been replaced with `:has()`. Of course, neither is supported by any major browser of note so it's a moot point. :( I can't wait to have that capability in CSS, though... It's about time! Thanks @Wh1T3h4Ckt for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried experimenting with sibling selectors? I don't think it'll achieve exactly what you want, but it might get you most of the way:

```
tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) ~ td,
tr:first-child th + td {  
  background: goldenrod
}
```

Or maybe:

```
tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(4),
tr:first-child td:nth-last-child(4) ~ td { background-color:blue; }
```

There is no parent selector in CSS.